# Jquery event calendar tool tip

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like some help with mouse-over on jquery.

An automatic mouse-over popup needs to occur on every event, on a jquery calendar.

Here's a similar example. However I'd like to create an automatic mouse-over on every event present on the calendar.

```js
    $(document).on('pageshow','#index',function(e,data){    
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
    
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
</head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
    
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>My Team</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        
        <div data-role="content">       
            <div id='calendar' style="width:100%;"></div>
        </div><!-- /content -->
    
    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have example for eventClick in documentation, for eventMouseover you can do the same thing (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/). 
Try below code:

```
//list of event...
],
  eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

    alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);

    // change the border color just for fun
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
}
```

Entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lang-all.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            lang: 'pl',
            editable: true,

            events: [
                 {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }

            ],
            eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

    alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);

    // change the border color just for fun
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
}
        });

    });

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: script for Mouse event not Working

Comment: What do you mean? I tested above code and it worked every time my mouse cursor was upon event on calendar.

Comment: Can you please configure entire code jgr . that will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventMouseover/

```
eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) { // add event name to title attribute on mouseover
        var title = event.title;
        $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', title);
  }
```